# See a history/log of moved files?

Tags: windows-7

Is it at all possible to see a log of files that have been moved, and to where?

..particularly, I would like to know if a file/folder had been moved from my PC to a usb stick.

Is there any way to see this?

The folder has mysteriously disappeared from my PC (and not even in recycle bin).

...worried someone has taken it.

I have it back - by doing system restore - but I would like to know what I asked above.

It was no where before I did restore...not in recylce bin and I search the whole C drive.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any logging enabled? Why not check the USB stick?

Comment: I don't know that it was put on a USB at all....I think someone may have gone on my PC and put it on their USB.

Comment: So you left your PC unattended and logged in?

Answer (score 3):

> **I would like to know if a file/folder had been moved from my PC to a usb stick**

So far as I know, On a standard install of Windows 7, there is no log kept of such actions by supplied utilities like Windows Explorer or the command prompt.

There is an auditing facility that you can turn on. [Apply or Modify Auditing Policy Settings for a Local File or Folder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771070.aspx). This might help in future, or it might just fill your hard disk with audit logs you'll never read.

---

If you are worried about someone misusing information on your computer, you should take a broader look at security options available

- On the fly disk or folder encryption
- Overt file encryption
- Enforce use of passwords (or better) to log-in / resume
- Enforce quick time-outs for locking or make it a habit to explicitly lock from Start menu..
- Restrict assignment of administrative rights to user logins